# Custom background cover by theme background

Tags: css, intel-xdk

In XDK, App Designer for App Framework. I set the page background image *(index_main.less.css)* but in simulator/preview my background image doesn't show up. After inspect element, I found out the theme's **"#afui.ios7 .panel, #afui.ios7 #modalContainer"** *(af.ui.min.css)* css rule cover my background image.

My question, how to prevent the theme's default CSS to cover my background image.

My CSS files loading arrangement should be correct:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/2.1/css/af.ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/2.1/css/icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this

```html
<style type="text/css">
            div { 
              background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
              background-image:url(images/Strabburg.jpg);
              background-position:center center;
              background-repeat:no-repeat;
              background-attachment:fixed;
              background-size:cover;
            }
        </style>
```

after

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
```